# How to get the last modified files in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to create a list the names of the files which have been last modified at

```
 http://www.searchr.us/web-search/
```

I want to show these file names on my Homepage and they should change according to the last modified files !!

Comment: I have no idea what files you are talking about. Can you clarify?

Comment: This got nothing to do with neither JavaScript nor HTML, removed both of these tags. With over 40 question you should start tagging your questions better.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use this function

```
function listdir_by_date($path){
$dir = opendir($path);
$list = array();
while($file = readdir($dir)){
    if ($file != '.' and $file != '..'){
        // add the filename, to be sure not to
        // overwrite a array key
        $mtime = filemtime($data_path . $file) . ',' . $file;
        $list[$mtime] = $file;
    }
}
closedir($dir);
krsort($list);
return $list;}
```

You can then loop through $list and echo accordingly.

Basically You can use the filemtime() function described [here.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php)

Comment: This works when the folder is within your webserver. If you want to get the data from the webserver you will have to modify the function.

Comment: @5416339 care to elaborate why you accept an answer that is **not** solving your problem? The given solution works for local file only while - according to your question - you want to fetch the mtime of remote files, which is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible.

See the [manual for `filemtime`:](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php)

> As of PHP 5.0.0, this function can also be used with some URL wrappers. Refer to List of Supported Protocols/Wrappers for a listing of which wrappers support stat() family of functionality.

and the [manual page for HTTP/HTTPS stream wrappers](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php):

```
Supports stat()     No
```

Answer (score 0):

Chech out this GitHub repository: [**ZFYL/zipper**](https://github.com/ZFYL/zipper)

Download index.php and **zipper.php** and insert them in any accessable directory on your server. Then opening it in the browser, setup the main page (from date, until date, path to look recursively)

And after that you can eithe list those files modified in the given time period.

Or you can use the function library **zipper.php**, include it, and read the [**How to use functions from ZFYL zipper in your code**](https://github.com/ZFYL/zipper/wiki/Functions) in the repo wiki on GitHub.